# C++ Locking stream operators with mutex

Tags: multithreading, c++11, logging, stdout, mutex

I need to lock stdout in my logging application to prevent string interleaving in multi-thread applications logging to stdout. Can't figure out how to use move constructor or std::move or sth else to move unique_lock to another object.

I created objects for setting configs and encapsulation and figured out how to lock stdout with static std::mutex to lock from these objects (called shards).

Something like this works for me:

```
l->log(1, "Test message 1");
```

While that is fine and could be implemented with templates and variable number of parameters I would like to approach more stream-like possibilities. I am looking for something like this:

```
*l << "Module id: " << 42 << "value: " << 42 << std::endl;
```

I dont want to force users to precompute string with concatenation and to_string(42) I just want to find a way to lock stdout.

My approach so far was to create operator <<  and another object locked stream, as was suggested in other answers. Things is I can't figure how to move mutex to another object. My code:

```
locked_stream& shard::operator<<(int num)
{
    static std::mutex _out_mutex;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_out_mutex);
    //std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock (_out_mutex);
    std::cout << std::to_string(num) << "(s)";
    locked_stream s;
    return s;
}
```

After outputting input to std::cout I woould like to move lock into object stream.

Comment: Not sure if the comment will be appreciated, but what I would do in this situation is to offload logging onto another thread. The logging thread will be writing to stdout without any locks, while the other threads can send the messages over a lock-free queue. Way less contention and more throughput, and no need for weaving locks through stream operations. I'll add an answer regardless.

Comment: I do appreciate it!
I will try to merge your answer and existing code, but will keep your suggestion in mind! Might as well try to rewrite it that way later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, I would be careful not to use static locks in functions, as you will get a different lock for each stream operator you create.

What you need is to lock some "output lock" when a stream is created, and unlock it when the stream is destroyed. You can piggie back on existing stream operations if you're just wrapping std::ostream. Here's a working implementation:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>


class locked_stream
{
    static std::mutex s_out_mutex;

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock_;
    std::ostream* stream_; // can't make this reference so we can move

public:
    locked_stream(std::ostream& stream)
        : lock_(s_out_mutex)
        , stream_(&stream)
    { }

    locked_stream(locked_stream&& other)
        : lock_(std::move(other.lock_))
        , stream_(other.stream_)
    {
        other.stream_ = nullptr;
    }

    friend locked_stream&& operator << (locked_stream&& s, std::ostream& (*arg)(std::ostream&))
    {
        (*s.stream_) << arg;
        return std::move(s);
    }

    template <typename Arg>
    friend locked_stream&& operator << (locked_stream&& s, Arg&& arg)
    {
        (*s.stream_) << std::forward<Arg>(arg);
        return std::move(s);
    }
};

std::mutex locked_stream::s_out_mutex{};

locked_stream locked_cout()
{
    return locked_stream(std::cout);
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    locked_cout() << "hello world: " << 1 << 3.14 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here it is on ideone: https://ideone.com/HezJBD

Also, forgive me, but there will be a mix of spaces and tabs up there because of online editors being awkward.